# Can I use multiple Sauce Connect instances in Bamboo?

Tags: bamboo, saucelabs

We are starting to use Bamboo for CI, and we will be adding the Sauce OnDemand plugin to Bamboo. Looking through Sauce Labs tutorials, it appears that only one Sauce Connect instance can be added to Bamboo. Is it possible to add more than one Sauce Connect instance?

I ask because we have separate product teams that each have their own Sauce Labs account. We need Sauce Labs to bill each team separately per month, so that's why we have multiple accounts instead of using sub-accounts. But...all of our products will eventually be built through Bamboo, and we'd eventually like to all have integrated Sauce Labs tests that run during the build process. Product team A will need to use Sauce Connect tunnel A, and product team B will need to use Sauce Connect tunnel B within Bamboo. I'd just like to know if this is possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Sauce Bamboo plugin *should* support multiple Sauce Connect instances, however only a single Sauce Connect process will be run per Sauce user.  Each Bamboo job will need to have a specific Sauce username/access key defined, and you will also need to configure the Bamboo job to use separate ports for Sauce Connect (via the 'Selenium Port' configuration field).

This isn't something we've widely tested though, so if you find any issues with it, please feel free to raise a [support request](http://support.saucelabs.com/) with Sauce Labs:)